# Configurar Samba Version 3.6.3 en SUSE LINUX ENTERPRISE SERVER 11

Tags: samba, opensuse

Hola estimados compañeros. He terminado de configurar un servidor samba en mi servidor de suse enterprise. En el encabezado están las versiones. El problema es que no logro configurar autenticarme con el usuario "juan" que pertenece al grupo "grpsamba" en Windows, me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les comparto la configuración del archivo smb.conf
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿dónde puede estar el problema?

Gracias por su apoyo desde ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de tanto probar por fin pudo resolverlo. El error no era por una mala configuración en el archivo de samba sino era de Windows, específicamente estaba relacionado a que tenía una UNIDAD DE RED asignada a "saturno_tmp", al cual intentaba ingresar.

Para resolver el problema borré todas las unidades de red con el comando: net use * /delete ... luego reinicié... volví a intentar conectar a la unidad compartida y pude... Les comparto por si acaso la configuración que estoy usando para compartir una carpeta con login:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]